# WPF: setting DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty of DataGridTextColumn causes unwanted side effects

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to set the background value of a DataGridTextColumn when the underlying datasource property has a certain value. That works but when the user selects the row in the datagrid the normal behaviour would be that the cell gets blue but in this case the background is not set (return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; ?) the cell stays white and because the font color is set to white on selection u see no value :)

[image]

expected:

[image]

Is it somehow possible to keep the normal/default behaviour when the row is selected?
The colums are automatically added to the datagrid the code to add a converter for the BackgroundProperty:

```
    var column = DtgMatrix.Columns[0] as DataGridTextColumn;
    var style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, new Binding()
    {
      Path = new PropertyPath("SomeFieldName"),
      Converter = new BrushConverter(),
      Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    }));

    column.CellStyle = style;

public class BrushConverter : IValueConverter
{

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value as string) && value == "boo" )
    {
      return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCoral);
    }
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
  }


  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Trigger` to only set the `Background` property when the cell is not selected:

```
var column = DtgMatrix.Columns[0] as DataGridTextColumn;
var style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
var trigger = new Trigger()
{
    Property = DataGridCell.IsSelectedProperty,
    Value = false
};
trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("SomeFieldName"),
    Converter = new BrushConverter(),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
}));
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);

column.CellStyle = style;
```